# Header checkbox can not be checked when clicked in jQuery Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jQUery Grid I added checkbox manually in the header(without using multiselect properties).
Now I would like to do header checkbox in jQuery Grid should be checked and unchecked when clicked.
Can anyone kindly suggest me a reasonable solution?

```
 function showDepartmentGrid(id) {
    $('#list_department_div').append('<table id="list_department"></table>');     
    $("#list_department").jqGrid({
        data: eventReceiveDepartments,
        datatype: "local",  
        colNames:[
            **'<input type="checkbox" onchange="checkAll(this)" name="chk[]"/>',**        
            dictWords['user_department'],
            'eventId',
            'belongingDepartment',
            'department'
        ],         
        colModel:[
            **{name: 'receive',
                class:'chcktbl',
                cellEdit: true,
                edittype: 'checkbox',
                sortable:false,
                align: 'center',
                editoptions: {value: "true:false"},
                formatter: "checkbox",
                width: '40',
                formatoptions: {disabled: false}
            },**
            {name:'departmentName',width: 170},
            {name: 'eventId', hidden:true},
            {name: 'belongingDepartment', hidden:true},
            {name: 'department', hidden:true}
        ],
        multiselect: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 250,
        shrinkToFit:false,
        rowNum: receiveDepartments.length,
        //caption: 'User master',
        //rownumbers: true,
        caption: dictWords['user_department'],
    });
}

**function checkAll(ele) {      
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    if (ele.checked) {
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                checkboxes[i].checked = true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            console.log(i)
            if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                checkboxes[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
};**
```

I tried this way, set alert message in the checkAll function as well, alert message has shown but checkbox has not checked.(For more specification kindly check the **  ** portion code)

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <= 4.7?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I resolved the issue.I have added id and class field inside Input of (colName)

```
colNames:["<input id='headCheck' class='hdCheck' type='checkbox'/>" ]
```

Not need to add any array in name field.

Then inside of jquery grid, in load complete method I wrote checked unchecked logic for header checkbox.

```
         loadComplete: function () {  
            //header checkbox made clickable            
            $('.hdCheck').parent().removeClass('ui-jqgrid-sortable');
            var allRows=[];
            allRows = $('#list_department').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            if ($("#headCheck").change(function(){
               if ($(this).is(':checked')){
                    isAllDepratment= true;                     
               }else{
                    isAllDepratment= false;
               } 
               allRows.forEach(function(id) {
                    checkUncheckDepartment(id,isAllDepratment);
               });
           }));                                                        
        }
    // This method responsible for checked each row checkbox depends on 'rowid'
    // which satisfied my requirement.shared if helps anyone.  
    function checkUncheckDepartment(rowid, isAllDepratment) {
       var list = kmcUI.getjqGridList({id: '#list_department'});
       var data = list.getRowData(rowid);
       for (var i in receiveDepartments) {
         if (data['eventId'] == receiveDepartments[i].eventId && 
           data['belongingDepartment']==receiveDepartments[i].belongingDepartment &&
           data['department'] == receiveDepartments[i].department
            ) {  
            if (isAllDepratment == true){
                receiveDepartments[i].receive = isAllDepratment;
                list.setRowData(rowid, receiveDepartments[i]);
                break;  
            }else{
                receiveDepartments[i].receive = isAllDepratment;
                list.setRowData(rowid, receiveDepartments[i]);
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The commented  part in the code is this line:

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

With this line all the checkboxes are get including the header one and is set according to the condition.

Another thing is that you will need to stopPropagation, since in the header of jqGrid is attached another click event. So in order this to work, you will need first to pass 
add a class in your checkbox and pass the event parameter and second to return e.stopPropagation(); at end of your function.

```
...
colNames:[
    '<input type="checkbox" onchange="checkAll(this, event)" class ="myclass" name="chk[]"/>',
...
```

and the function can look like this:

```
function checkAll(ele, e) {     
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    if (ele.checked) {
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if(!$(checkboxes[i]).hasClass('myclass')) {
                if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                    checkboxes[i].checked = true;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if(!$(checkboxes[i]).hasClass('myclass')) {
                if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                    checkboxes[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    e.stopPropagation();        
}
```